# adding ['ID'] in echo""

Tags: php

Hi this is my initial Html :

```
<a  class="item-img-box inner" href="<?php echo $item_casino_title_url; ?>" <?php echo $the_thumb_options; ?>>
                    <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image($item_image['ID'], 'casinos-size-new'); ?>
                </a>
```

I need that my img with no click if the href is empty
But cant write the right way

```
<?php 
$link1 =  $item_casino_title_url ;
         
if (!empty($link1)) {
    echo  "<span  class='item-img-box inner'  $the_thumb_options; >
                wp_get_attachment_image($item_image['ID'],'casinos-size-new'); 
           </span>";
}
else {
    echo  "<a  class='item-img-box inner' href='$item_casino_title_url;' $the_thumb_options; >
                wp_get_attachment_image($item_image['ID'],'casinos-size-new'); 
           </a>";
}
?>
```

Can't find the mistakes ?
thx

Comment: I suspect you meant for the calls to `wp_get_attachment_image` to be *outside* the string literal, no?

Comment: No simply need to desactivate the href , so no click on my image, can't write the right syntax in the echo""

Comment: So `wp_get_attachment_image()` isn't a PHP function that you want to call, and put its value in the HTML? This code will put the literal string `wp_get_attachment_image` in the HTML.

Comment: yes this is working 
<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image($item_image['ID'], 'casinos-size'); ?>
but when i inject it in the echo it's print me the string wp_get_attachment_image

Comment: @tarektemimi: *"it's print me the string wp_get_attachment_image"* - Because that's what a literal string is.  It doesn't call a function, it just prints a string.  Which is [what you said you wanted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68107772/adding-id-in-echo#comment120376134_68107772), no?  Otherwise remove it from the literal string.

Answer (score 2):

You need to either remove the quotes around `ID`

```
    echo  "<span  class='item-img-box inner'  $the_thumb_options >
                wp_get_attachment_image($item_image[ID],'casinos-size-new'); 
           </span>";
```

or put braces around the variable

```
    echo  "<span  class='item-img-box inner'  $the_thumb_options >
                wp_get_attachment_image({$item_image['ID']},'casinos-size-new'); 
           </span>";
```

or use string concatenation instead of interpolation

```
    echo  "<span  class='item-img-box inner'  $the_thumb_options >
                wp_get_attachment_image(" . $item_image['ID'] . ",'casinos-size-new'); 
           </span>";
```

You also shouldn't have `;` after the variables inside `<span ...>` and inside the `href` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `{}` in the string injection to avoid those problems:

```
<?php
$link1 = $item_casino_title_url;

if (!empty($link1))
{
    echo "<span  class='item-img-box inner'  $the_thumb_options; >
                     wp_get_attachment_image({$item_image['ID']},'casinos-size-new'); 
                </span>";
}
else
{
    echo "<a  class='item-img-box inner' href='$item_casino_title_url;' $the_thumb_options; >
                     wp_get_attachment_image({$item_image['ID']},'casinos-size-new'); 
                </a>";
}
?>
```

Comment: @tarektemimi you can't inject a function call in PHP, you have to break the string a concatenate the pieces (check other answer)